# Converting a time string such as "1d" to seconds

Tags: lua

I'm currently looking for a way to take a users input and convert it to seconds. If a person/user types any of the following inputs below (with any integer) then it will return the second equivalent of that

Inputs examples would be: 1y, 1mth, 1d, 1h, 1m, 1s

I have tried multiple things so far, checking for the last letter in the input, etc.. None have come to exactly what I'm looking for sadly.

Comment: I would start by writing a function that accepts the string input, figures out which one it is and returns the appropriate number of seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your inputs are structured as (one or more ASCII digits) followed by (one or more ASCII letters). You can describe this with the [pattern](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1) `^(%d+)(%a+)$`:

```
function parseDuration(input)
    local count, unit = input:match "^(%d+)(%a+)$"
    if not count then
        return nil, "invalid duration `" .. input .. "`"
    end
```

Now you need to just do unit conversion. A table of seconds in each unit is one very clear way to do it:

```
    local SECONDS_PER = {
        s = 1,
        m = 60,
        h = 60 * 60,
        d = 24 * 60 * 60,
        w = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60,
        -- etc
    }

    if not SECONDS_PER[unit] then
        return nil, "unknown unit `" .. unit .. "`"
    end

    return tonumber(count) * SECONDS_PER[unit]
end
```